# 4 digit hostname increase by 1 using ansible

Tags: ansible

I want hostname should be increase by 1. for example, if my hostname is abc-0001 then it should generate next hostname like abc-0002.

basically, I am trying to get vm list from vcenter and increase hostname by 1 from last hostname. then i will use that hostname for new deployment.
initially, I am splitting server name in 2 part. firstpart is abc and server_list is second part is used to increase value by 1.

when i run the playbook, I am getting next server name in abc-2 instead of abc-0002

```
- set_fact:
    new_vm_name: "{{ firstpart }}-{{ (((server_list | sort | max).split('-'))[1]| int) + 1 }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to handle this is to use [python string formating](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

In Jinja2/ansible, this is done with the `%` operator:

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a msg="{{ '%04d' % 1 }}"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "0001"
}
```

In your specific case, the following should do the trick:

```yaml
next_vm_number: "{{ (server_list | sort | max).split('-')[1] | int + 1 }}"
new_vm_name: "{{ '%s-%04d' % (firstpart, next_vm_number | int) }}"
```